# Regular Expression for Splunk - extract between two phrases across multiple lines.

Tags: regex, splunk

I am trying to extract log data in splunk and my current usecase is more complicated that what the "regex builder" will allow for.  Consider the below example, I would like to extract all the text **between** two phrases.  I can get small, one line samples to work between two words, but I've not been able to get this to work at all.  The separate line breaks are not helping either.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Phrase1: **Stuff.Applications.Business.StuffApi.Common.Exceptions.ValidationException:**

Phrase2:
**at Stuff.Applications.Business.StuffApi.Web.Controllers.Stuff.Things**

Example Data:

```
02/26/2018 02:17:08 PM
LogName=Stuff
SourceName=StuffApi
EventCode=400
EventType=2
Type=Error
ComputerName=Stuff.things.Words
TaskCategory=%1
OpCode=Info
RecordNumber=3129
Keywords=Classic
Message=2018-02-26 14:17:08,767 [63] ERROR Things [(null)] - Something Number:  ; Something Number: 9999999999 ; Source Application: ABCD ; Error Type: Validation ; Response Status Code: 400
Stuff.Applications.Business.StuffApi.Common.Exceptions.ValidationException: Validation Errors: Error:ErrorInfo.Error cannot be greater than the current date: 2/26/2018 12:00:00 AM, Incoming Value:2/27/2018 12:00:00 AM;
   at Stuff.Applications.Business.StuffApi.Web.Controllers.Stuff.Things(SomeRequest request) in f:\Builds\348\Policy Systems\V.12_Release.Applications.Business.Things\src\src\Web\Controllers\Stuff.cs:line 288
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex

```
Stuff\.Applications\.Business\.StuffApi\.Common\.Exceptions\.ValidationException:(?<text>[\s\S]+)at Stuff\.Applications\.Business\.StuffApi\.Web\.Controllers\.Stuff\.Things
```